# Magnetic field around an Inductor?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits

If a voltage source is connected to an inductor magnetic field is formed around the inductor which induces equal and opposite voltage in the inductor. But then the magnetic field collapses with time due to which voltage induced in an inductor becomes less and less with time and that makes the current to rise in inductor as  the voltage opposite to the source is getting less and less.

My question is what makes the magnetic field to collapse with time ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does current flow if back emf equals to applied voltage](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/308979)

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. Why do you claim that the magnetic field collapses? Why do you then as us to explain something which you are claiming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If a voltage source is connected to an inductor magnetic field is formed around the inductor which induces equal and opposite voltage in the inductor.

When the voltage source is connected to the inductor the current through the inductor is zero and there is no magnetic field.

The opposing voltage due to the inductor is dependent on the rate of change of current with time $\frac{dI}{dt}$ **not the magnitude of the current**, $V_{\rm inductor} = L\frac{dI}{dt}$.

So in a theoretical circuit with no resistance or capacitance the current (and the magnetic field due to the inductor) will rise indefinitely $\frac{dI}{dt}=\frac{V_{\rm supply}}{L}$.

If there is resistance $R$ in the circuit then the current starts from zero and over time tends to a value of $\frac{V_{\rm supply}}{R}$.

Comment: current will rise in the inductor in this case when opposing voltage across inductor will fall. then the battery voltage will become more than the opposing inductor voltage and then the current will be able to rise. you told that rate of change of current will cause equal and opposite voltage/indefinite voltage across the inductor but my question is that what then makes the current to rise opposing voltage of the inductor to fall ?

Comment: As I wrote in my answer the current will continue to rise if there is no resistance in the circuit.If there is a resistance in the circuit then as the current increases the voltage across the resistor will increase and so the voltage across the inductor will fall such that the voltage across the resistor plus the voltage across the inductor is equal to the volt6age of the supply.A lower voltage across the inductor implies a lower rate of change of current. This continues until the voltage across the resistor is equal to the voltage across the supply and there is no voltage across the inductor