# Confused about inductors and how they "react to changes in current"

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, batteries, inductance

When you have an RL circuit and you close the switch allowing current to flow, I always thought that the inductor opposes that sudden increase in current as if it was just a circuit without an inductor (so current just shot up to X ampere). This causes a change in magnetic flux through the inductor's coils and thus producing a back EMF equal to the terminal voltage across the battery. Initially at t=0 this causes the current to be 0 as there is no potential difference across the resistor. Over time, the change in current decreases so there is less back EMF until there is no change in current so the voltage across the inductor is 0

[image]

What I'm confused about is how the voltage across the inductor is determined by dI/dt as in this equation [image] which is the gradient of the current in the graph. However, isn't the change in current in the graph caused by the inductor having back EMF in the first place. For example at t=0, dI/dT is 60A per second but isn't this because the inductor has already produced a back EMF initially as a result of that sudden increase in current when the switch was closed so it is at 0A as in the graph. What it looks like to me is the gradient which is used to get the voltage across the inductor is based off something that already requires the voltage across the inductor so it's like a recursive sequence.

If anyone could help clarify my error in the understanding of inductors, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: In a resistor, is the current determined by the voltage or is the voltage determined by the current?

Comment: @ThePhoton, I actually never thought about this out. I don't really know, I would think that you get the potential difference across a resistor and with its resistance, that determines the current. Don't know if that's how it actually works though.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does current flow if back emf equals to applied voltage](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/308979/)

Comment: Also, search the site for other questions with the term "back-emf". Very similar questions get asked fairly frequently (although I had to go through a couple pages of search hits to get to the one that matched yours very closely).

Comment: Also see this question on EE Stackexchange: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/248764/